# Javascript regex replace a pattern without touching a similar pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have string like this:

```
var str = 'SELECT * FROM table_a JOIN table_b JOIN (SELECT * FROM table_c) c JOIN table_d';
```

I wish to insert a database name between '`JOIN`' and '`table_a`'; but I do not wish to insert the database name between '`JOIN`' and the subquery.

I.e., after the replacement, the string should look like:

```
   result = 'SELECT * FROM table_a JOIN database.table_b JOIN (SELECT * FROM table_c) c JOIN database.table_d';
```

Is there way to use regex to insert the database name between JOIN and table names without touching the "JOIN (" pattern?

Imagine there are dozens of tables with different names in the string...

Comment: My advice is to use a query builder and not mangle your queries with regex replacements. That will solve your current problem and prevent the upcoming problems I can see you running into.

Answer (score 0):

The stupid way is to insert the database name first, and revert it back if any 'JOIN database.(' is found:

```
var str = 'SELECT * FROM table_a JOIN table_b JOIN (SELECT * FROM table_c) c JOIN table_d';

str.replace(/JOIN/g, 'JOIN database.').replace(/JOIN\sdatabase\.\(/g, '/JOIN (');
```

But this is very inefficient for large queries. Hope someone can share some smarter idea.